# Is there a to add a default selection to a dropdown menu generated in a for loop using data pulled from SQL in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

I am writing a program that allows the user to update customer information. One of the fields that can be updated is the country that the customer is from. The country can be updated using a dropdown menu that pulls all of the country names from an SQL database and is dynamically generated using a for loop. However, I also want to program the dropdown menu to automatically select the country that the customer is from. Is there a way to do this while keeping the for loop?

```
<label>Country:</label>
        <select name="countryCode">
            <?php foreach ($countries as $country) : ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $country['countryCode']; ?>"><?php echo $country['countryName']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
```

Code for pulling customer data from the database.

```
    $customer_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'customerID');
    if ($customer_id == NULL || $customer_id == FALSE) {
        $error = "Missing or incorrect customer ID.";
        include('../errors/error.php');
    } else { 
        $customers = select_customer($customer_id);
        $countries = get_countries();
        include('customer_update.php');  
    }
}
```

```
function select_customer($customer_id) {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM customers
              WHERE customerID = :customer_id';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':customer_id', $customer_id);
    $statement->execute();
    $select = $statement->fetch();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $select;
}
```

Code for pulling country data.

```
function get_countries() {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM countries
              ORDER BY countryName';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $countries = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $countries;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `selected` tag to an option depending on the data. It could be something like this:

```
<label>Country:</label>
        <select name="countryCode">
            <?php foreach ($countries as $country) : ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $country['countryCode']; ?>" <?=($country['countryCode'] == $customers['country_code']) ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?php echo $country['countryName']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
```

I assumed here that your customer data (`$customers` variable) has the `country_code` field.

I hope you've got the idea.

PS: the `<?=` statement is a kind of a shortcut to the `<?php echo`.

Comment: Running the code verbatim gave me an "unidentified index" error. Altering `$country['countryCode'] == $customers['country_code']` to `$country['countryCode'] == $customers['countryCode']` fixes this, as the $customers array is data taken from the customers table. However, it still does not seem to work. Inspecting the webpage with a web browser shows that it adds an empty selected attribute to the option element when it finds a match. Like this: `<option value="US" selected="">United States</option>` Compare to an option element that does not match. `<option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>`

Comment: Could you try `selected="selected"`?

Comment: If I change the line to say `<option value="<?php echo $country['countryCode']; ?>" <?=($country['countryCode'] == 'countryCode') ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>><?php echo $country['countryName']; ?></option>` then it does not even add the empty selected attribute when it finds a match.

Comment: I should also add that it seems to not find a match at all unless I compare it directly to the country code. For example, if I try `<option value="<?php echo $country['countryCode']; ?>" <?=($country['countryCode'] == 'US') ? 'selected' : '' ?>></option>` then it will find a match. However, using `<option value="<?php echo $country['countryCode']; ?>" <?=($country['countryCode'] == customers['countryCode']) ? 'selected' : '' ?>></option>` then it will never find a match, even if the value of customers['countryCode'] is set to 'US'.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it worked out. The code `<option value="<?php echo $country['countryCode']; ?>"<?=($country['countryCode'] == $customers['countryCode']) ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?php echo $country['countryName']; ?></option>` seems to do the trick. I did notice that changes in the dropdown menu code did not apply when I refresh the page, but do apply if I manually travel back to the page.